# Nxlog - Collecting data from SQL Table

Tags: nxlog

Looking to collect log information being written to a MSSQL Server table and forward it to Graylog using nxlog or similar.

I see a lot of information about checking logs with nxlog but nothing related to how this could be done, does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, your options are:

- NXLog EE + im_odbc on Windows or Linux
- NXLog CE + im_dbi + freetds driver on Linux